# How to append from JSON after filter on key value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON where I use a jQuery `$.each` function to append the data to a table. I do an if statement to check if a value matches a string.

In my last table column, I need to get data from another text filter. So if the data value matches my filter, then append it as the last `td`

```
dataset = [
  "river": {
    "year": "2016",
    "name": "Silver Creek",
    "series": "Caught fish",
    "weight": "100 kg",

  },
  "river": {
    "year": "2016",
    "name": "Silver Creek",
    "series": "Released fish",
    "weight": "60 kg"
  }
];

$(dataset).each(function(i, data){

  if (data.year === "2016" && data.series === "Caught fish") {
    $('tbody').append('<tr class="river"><td>' + this.year + '</td><td>' + this.name + </td><td>' + this.weight + </td></tr>')
  } if (data.year === "2016" && data.series === "Released fish") {
    $('tr.river').append('<td>' + this.weight + '</td>')
  }

});
```

The code above does not do but I want, but may be a hint of what I want to achieve.

What I need as a table row:

```
YEAR | NAME         | CAUGHT | RELEASED
2016 | Silver Creek | 100 kg | 60 kg
```

Any suggestions? Could I build a new variable based on the dataset outside the `$.each` function?

Comment: You are missing a quote here `this.weight + </...`

Comment: i think youre having trouble because your data is organized poorly. data like this would be more helpful for you: `"river": { year: 2016, name: "Silver Creek", caughtWeight: "100kg", releasedWeight: "60kg" }`. you can find out what its series is based on whether it has a released weight or not.

Comment: This is the way data comes from the API. Originally in json-stat format.

Answer (score 1):

Use the **[:contains](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)** selector for released fish to see if the year and waterbody already exist in the table:

```js
var dataset = [
  {"year": "2015","name": "Cedar Creek","series": "Caught fish","weight": "90 kg"},
  {"year": "2016","name": "Silver Creek","series": "Caught fish","weight": "60 kg"},
  {"year": "2015","name": "Cedar Creek","series": "Released fish","weight": "40 kg"},
  {"year": "2016","name": "Silver Creek","series": "Released fish","weight": "60 kg"}
];

dataset.forEach(function(data) {
  if(data.series === 'Caught fish') {
    $('tbody').append('<tr class="river"><td>' + data.year + '<td>' + data.name + '<td>' + data.weight);
  } else {
    $('tr:contains(' + (data.year + data.name) + ')').append('<td>' + data.weight);
  }
});
```

```css
tr > * {border: 1px solid #ddd;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr><th>YEAR<th>NAME<th>CAUGHT<th>RELEASED
</table>
```